# Spring STS 4 PropertiesLauncher start parameter

Tags: spring-tools-4

Spring STS 4 seems to launch a separate process called PropertiesLauncher. I guess it's for supporting the Language Server Protocol.

How can we customize the start parameters of this process, in particular how can we increase the max heap size (-Xmx1024m seems to be the default)?

I notice from time to time a slow down which seems to be related to increased garbage collection because of a full old generation.

Comment: there is no way to customize these start parameters yet, so please raise an enhancement request at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues - in addition to that we would, of course, interested to learn more about the heap utilization in your case, so maybe we could collaborate a bit to find out why that heap gets to that size and how to reduce that in future versions. Would you be up for that? If so, it would be awesome if you could open another issue where we can do the footprint analysis.

Comment: @MartinLippert is there a way to turn off this bavkground process ? Unchecking all options in the Eclipse preferences for "Spring Boot Language Server" doesn't help.

Comment: @MartinLippert I've created two new issues in your issue tracker as requested.

Comment: There is a preference section called `LanguageServers` where you can disable the Spring Boot Language Server for all the content-types it is registered for (Java Source + Boot property files). That should completely disable the language server and never cause that additional process to startup. However, as a side effect, you would loose the features that it contributes. Therefore, we should definitely solve the underlying issue, I will follow-up on the issues that you created. Many thanks for that, btw.